Error al llenar tabla con datatable jquery ajax ASP.NET
estoy intentando llenar una tabla html a través de un datatable el cual trae la información de una base de datos. Dentro de los parámetros del ajax para traer la info de la base de datos está un dato que me permite solo extraer los registros de ese parámetro, pero al ejecutarlo mediante el clic de un botón buscar me saca un error donde dice que el parámetro es nulo, pero el parámetro es el valor seleccionado en un combo que lleno al cargar la página. Este es el código que realizo. Inicialmente el de la tabla y posteriormente el script
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 for="txtLista" class="form-label">Integrantes</h5>
            <table id="tabla" class="display cell-border" style="width: 100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Fecha nacimiento</th>
                        <th>Edad</th>
                        <th>Sexo</th>
                        <th>Tipo documento</th>
                        <th>Numero documento</th>
                        <th>Editar/Eliminar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

El script es el siguiente:
@section scripts{
<script>
var tabladata;

$(document).ready(function () {
       $("<option>").attr({ "value": "0", "disabled": "disabled", "selected": "true" }).text("Seleccionar").appendTo("#cbbunidad");
       jQuery.ajax({

        url: "@Url.Action("ListarUnidad", "Mantenedor")",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

                if (data.data != null) {
                    $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                            $("<option>").attr({"value":item.uniId}).text(item.uniNombre).appendTo("#cbbunidad");
                    })
                }
        },
        error: function (error) {
                console.log(error)
        }
        });
})

$("#btnBuscar").on("click", function () {

        tabladata = $("#tabla").DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            responsive: true,
            ordering: false,
            "ajax": {
                url: "@Url.Action("ListarIntegrantesUnidad", "Mantenedor")",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ idUnidad: $("#cbbunidad option:selected").val() })
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "intNombre" },
                { "data": "intFechaNacimiento" },
                { "data": "intEdad" },
                { "data": "intSexo" },
                { "data": "intTipoDocumento" },
                { "data": "intNumeroDocumento" },
                {
                    "defaultContent": '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-editar"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button>' +
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-retirar ms-2"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "searchable": false,
                    "width": "90px"
                }
            ],
            "language": {
                "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/2.0.2/i18n/es-ES.json",
            }
        })
})
</script>

}
Y el mensaje de error que se da es:

En el debugger el mensaje que obtengo es:

Soy relativamente nuevo en programación web y agradezco la ayuda que puedan prestarme.
En el controller Mantenimiento, el método que recibe los datos es:
[HttpGet] public JsonResult ListarIntegrantesUnidad(int idunidad) { 
List<EntidadIntegrantesUnidad> oLista = new 
List<EntidadIntegrantesUnidad>(); 
oLista = new CN_IntegrantesUnidad().ListarenUnidad(idunidad);
return Json(new { data = oLista }, 
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}

Para validar el dato que obtengo del combo generé una variable donde me aseguro el valor del parámetro obteniendo como resultado efectivamente el valor que corresponde pero me sigue arrojando el mismo error. El código donde hago el llamado al datatable es:
valorcombo = $("#cbbunidad").val();
//debugger

tabladata = $("#tabla").DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    responsive: true,
    ordering: false,
    "ajax": {
        url: "@Url.Action("ListarIntegrantesUnidad", "Mantenedor")",
        type: "GET",
        data: JSON.stringify({ intId: valorcombo }),
        //data: JSON.stringify({ intId: $("#cbbunidad option:selected").val() }),
        datatype: "json"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "intId" },
        { "data": "intNombre" },
        { "data": "intFechaNacimiento" },
        { "data": "intEdad" },
        { "data": "intSexo" },
        { "data": "intTipoDocumento" },
        { "data": "intNumeroDocumento" },
        { "data": "intRelacion" },
        {
            "defaultContent": '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-editar"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button>' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-retirar ms-2"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>',
            "orderable": false,
            "searchable": false,
            "width": "90px"
        }
    ],
    "language": {
        "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/2.0.2/i18n/es-ES.json",
    }
})


Ese error normalmente indica que el json que obtienes no cumple con los parámetros que el datatables tiene definidos, es decir, si has definido 7 columnas, el json quizas esta devolviendo solo 6 o quizas, aunque devuelva 7, en alguno de sus registros hay algun dato inválido en la columna idunidad. Por lo tanto revisa el json devuelto y comprueba si está correcto.

Inicialmente no existen registros en la respuesta recibida, lo que debería mostrar el datatable vacío.

Pues el error que dice que "el diccionario de parámetro contiene una entrada NULL para el parámetro 'idunidad'" parece que indique que algo devuelve, pues la entrada NULL no creo que se la saque de la manga, no se, en la pregunta no pones lo que devuelve realmente.  Míralo en el inspector, en las peticiones de red, en modo raw, de la respuesta que recibes, a ver si ves algo raro.

En el debugger, antes de iniciar la definición de la tabla, me muestra el valor correcto del combo que es la variable que utilizo como filtro para que me muestre los datos, pero una vez entra a la tabla es cuando ocurre el error. modifiqué pasando el parámetro de POST a GET pero sigue igual.
El método que utilizo en el controller Mantenedor es:

No pongas código en los comentarios, cuesta mucho de seguir y si viene alguien más a ayudarte no se lo va a leer. Ponlo en la pregunta pulsando sobre [edit] para modificar la misma.

Corregido masterguru, muchas gracias.

Por cierto, ahora que lo veo, pones "@Url.Action" y eso me suena a asp.  Agrega esa etiqueta en tu pregunta, pues a mi me descarta completamente al no tener ni idea de ese lenguaje.
